# Use of gather() in a loop, "key" and "value" as a variable

Tags: r, tidyr

I like to use `gather()` in loop, where values for the inputs of `gather()` `key` and `value` are a variable. Is this possible?

I also tried `gather()` with a standard variable (set outside the loop, without a index), but is doesn't work.

So, I assume, that it is not possible per definition of _gather()_to assign `key` and `value` to a variable.

In the documentation I found on **key** and **value**:

"...note that this kind of interface where symbols do not represent actual objects..."

I assume that's the answer.
But I'm not sure.

```
gather(Fragenummern.FB[i], Fragenummern.FI[i], 
       key = keyVar[i], value = ValueVar[i])
```

> Error: Must supply a symbol or a string as argument
>
> Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: What is `Fragenummern.FB[i]`  is it data and is it stored as string?

Comment: Not cleear, please update with a small reproducible example

Comment: It is a vector containing the column names of the data frame which should be processed.

Comment: sorry, then where is the `data` identifier

Comment: If the datasets are in a `list`, use `[[` for subsetting the list elements instead of `[`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this using `dplyr::gather` and `rlang` commands. In this example, you have your `df`, a vector of some variable names in `df` that you want to `gather`, and a vector of names for the newly gathered variables.

```r
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(260),ncol = 26))
names(df) <- letters

to_gather <- sample(letters,5)
new_names <- c('letter','value')

df %>% gather(key = !!new_names[1], value = !!new_names[2], enexpr(to_gather))
```

And you can loop over this and create multiple new data frames based on different subsets of variables to gather.

```r
lapply(1:2, function(x){
  to_gather <- sample(letters,5)
  df %>% gather(key = !!new_names[1], value = !!new_names[2], enexpr(to_gather))
  })
```